# Electrical on NXR gas oven not working

Tags: electrical, oven

My [NXR Pro oven](https://nxrproducts.com/products/nxr-pro-gas-range) has been having some issues. Before the oven would only sometimes ignite. And when it did ignite it would take 3-4mins. After some research it seemed like it was the igniter. I replaced the [igniter](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B09TDXNM5R?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) and it worked for about 10 minutes. Now not only the igniter isn't working, but the oven doesn't seem to be getting power anywhere. The oven light doesn't turn on and the range igniters aren't sparking either. Gas still flows fine. Not sure how to diagnose at this point. My best guess is that the igniter shorted out or died. The wiring connection for the oven igniter(see image) seems suspect, so maybe that caused it?

Update: I fixed the connectors. I confirmed with a multimeter that there is a connection there. Still no electric though.

[image]

Comment: Is this picture from before or after you fixed the suspect electrical connections? I'd hope it's a "before" pic, as that still looks pretty suspect. Also, can you provide a link to the instruction manual? Often, they include a trouble shooting section. One would presume you've confirmed the breaker hasn't tripped, but it's always good to ask the obvious questions...

Comment: Yea, it was a before photo. I like to think I'm not that sloppy. The problem was resolved. Breaker was fine. But the outlet itself needed to be reset. My guess is the bad wiring caused it to flip in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That connection needs to be fixed but probably isn't the main problem if it's just for the igniter. Check your breaker in the main panel  and then start testing voltages with a multimeter across the circuit.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it was the outlet that flipped(not the breaker). Things seem to work now. My guess is bad original wiring caused it. But now things seem fine.